# How to assign barplot/plot to a variable and recall at later stage

Tags: r, plot

How can I assign `plot` to a variable and have it printed it at later stage?
With lattice `xyplot` you can do it easily:

```
s <- xyplot((1:10)^2~1:10)
s
```

However not with base `plot`

```
a <- plot((1:10)^2,1:10)
```

What I have got is a `barplot` in a function:

```
funbar <- function(x) { barplot(x) }
variab <- funbar(1:10) # this plots the data
```

So I would like it to print at later stage by calling `variab`

In fact I have additional graphical functions in a function, something like this:

```
funbar <- function(x) { barplot(x); points(....); text(....) }
```

I could not find any info on this obvious part. The `plot=FALSE` doesn't help here.

EDIT: Here are the data for barplot taken from `?barplot`

```
require(grDevices) # for colours
tN <- table(Ni <- stats::rpois(100, lambda = 5))
r <- barplot(tN, col = rainbow(20))
```

EDIT 2: To answer Josh question as of why I would like to do this. Example:

```
layout(matrix(1:2, nrow=2, ncol=1))
tN <- table(Ni <- stats::rpois(100, lambda = 5))
r <- barplot(tN)
tN <- table(Ni <- stats::rpois(100, lambda = 5))
r <- barplot(tN)
```

Comment: Maybe have a look at `recordPlot()`. (There are other possibilities, but it's hard to say which will be most useful without more info about why you want to do this.)

Comment: Thanks Josh, `recordPlot()` did help!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this can be solved with `xy.coords`:

```
a <- xy.coords((1:10)^2,1:10) #plots nothing
```

And can be plotted later:

```
plot(a)
```

I came upon this idea by examining the code for `plot.default`.

As for `barplot`s, perhaps the `rect` function will accomplish something similar (as this seems to be at core of what `barplot.default` is doing).

Comment: thanks, it seems to work for `plot` but in fact I need that for `barplot` where I get erorr: `Error in -0.01 * height ...`

Comment: @Maximilian could you add an example using barplots, then? I just edited something in that may work, but don't have anything to test it with.